# Safe App starter suddenly not working

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have been developing a Safe App locally for about a month. A few days ago I started getting  this screen when trying to run the app in the Apps UI

[image]

I tried starting a fresh app with the template and get the same screen. I have reached out on Discord but have been ignored.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console logs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was my browser wallet was connected to a network where I don't have a deployed safe.